# Can bash grep "*" instead of "\*"?

Tags: bash

How can I grep asterisk `*` inside of a text file?
Here is my code :

```
if grep -F "\#$minute $hour $date $month $day $cr_user $comm" filecron; then
        echo "$minute $hour $date $month $day $cr_user $comm" > /dev/null 2>&1
        echo "data exist"

elif [[ -z $minute || -z $hour ]]; then
        echo "#$minute $hour $date $month $day $cr_user $comm" > /dev/null 2>&1
        echo "nothing to input"
        echo "" >> filecron

elif [[ $stat == "inactive" ]]; then
        echo "\#$minute $hour $date $month $day $cr_user $comm" >> filecron
        echo "input data inactive to filecron"

else
        echo "$minute $hour $date $month $day $cron_user $comm" >> filecron
        echo "input data active to filecron"

fi
```

Here is filecron contain

```
#30 07 03 09 RAB root bash /media/data/once.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
#* * * * * root bash /media/data/looping.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
#56 * * * * root bash /media/data/minutely.sh /dev/null 2>&1
#43 * * * * root bash /media/data/hourly.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
#54 11 * * * root bash /media/data/daily.sh /dev/null 2>&1
#00 12 * * RAB root bash /media/data/weekly.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
#30 20 15 * * root bash /media/data/monthly.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
#45 21 01 09 * root bash /media/data/yearly > /dev/null 2>&1
#15 16 31 08 MIN root bash /media/data/other.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
#30 07 * * * root bash /media/data/daily2.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
#30 10 * * * root bash /media/data/daily3.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
#45 17 17 * * root bash /media/data/monthly2.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
#00 18 * * SAB root bash /media/data/weekly2.sh > /dev/null 2>&1

#30 07 03 09 RAB root bash /media/data/once.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
#* * * * * root bash /media/data/looping.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
#56 * * * * root bash /media/data/minutely.sh /dev/null 2>&1
#43 * * * * root bash /media/data/hourly.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

But `grep` doesn't work if `$minute` or `$hour` or `$month` or `$day` or `$date` is `*`
So, how do I do this?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't have any regular expression patterns, and just want to match the string exactly, use the `-F` option to `grep` (or the older `fgrep` command):

```
if grep -F "#$minute $hour $date $month $day $cr_user $comm" filecron; then
```

Comment: I've try it, but variable still redirect into file.
It should be not redirect into file after I grep. Here example of file contain.
#30($minute) 15($hour) *($date) *($month) MON($day) root($cr_user) bash /media/data/test1.sh > /dev/null 2>&1($comm)
#* * * * * root bash /media/data/test2.sh > /dev/null 2>&1

How about that?
How should I write grep code for that?

Comment: I don't understand your question. There's no redirecting to a file in the question. It's just echoing to `/dev/null`, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Please update your question with an example of the `filecron` contents and the values of all the variables.

Comment: ohh sorry, i haven't explain it. before that code i echoing the variable into file. if the file has been contain that variable then varible echo into /dev/null otherwise echo into file. and what make confuse is when varible value is "*", grep doesn't work

Comment: The string has to match exactly, including the same number of spaces between words.

Comment: See code after empty line? it should be not exist right? because I had redirect it into /dev/null. But grep not work for that.

Comment: The empty line comes from `echo "" >> filecron`. Why do you do that?

Comment: just for "sign". I have to make it sure that no variable redirect twice.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "no variable redirect twice". Since you use `elif`, only one of the statement blocks will be executed. Anyway, I asked you to post the values of the variables, why won't you do that?

Comment: variable value is retrieved from database.
and variable is dynamic depend on which record is selected.
One line from filecron stands for one record from database which i store into variable. then echoing the variable into filecron.
should I include full code here sir?

Comment: Just show me the ones that came up when the script didn't work correctly.

Comment: I give up, that still doesn't show me the values of the variables.

Comment: okay no problem sir, thanks for helping me. maybe I should try the "tricky way" to tricking grep problem.

Comment: Using `-F` should solve the problem of `*` in the data. If you're still having problems, it's because of something else.